# Setting a constraint of a UILabel at run time does not seem to impact until viewDidLoad is done

Tags: autolayout, swift2

I am trying to set the width of a UILabel at run time. The width is set but trying to access it before viewDidLoad is done always return the old value.

I do not set width in storyboard.

I do set the translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints to false at run time

and it seems that the widths are set correctly post viewDidLoad.

How do I get access to the updated frame? Is there a way to access it before viewDidLoad finishes?

Answer (score 0):

As all I want to do is to draw a line under the full (new) width of the label, I call my drawUnderline method in `viewDidAppear(animated: Bool)` method.

This does the trick.

Not sure if it is the best place but that is the only place where I could access the new/updated width.